# Unable to login to AzureAD using WS-Federation SSO

Tags: c#, azure, ws-federation

I have old code for logging in with ADFS but now have an additional requirement for loggging in via AzureAD. The method in the Federation library which works fine with ADFS but not Azure AD is the following.

```
    public static void RedirectToIdentityProvider(string db_, string realmIdentifier_, FederationConfig config_)
    {
        try
        {
            var returnurl = "http://localhost/6420";

            FederationDatabaseFunctions db = new FederationDatabaseFunctions(db_);
            FederationData federationData = db.GetFederatedDataByRealm(realmIdentifier_);
            TrustedIssuerFederationMetadata metadata = new TrustedIssuerFederationMetadata(federationData);


            WSFederationAuthenticationModule wsFAM = new WSFederationAuthenticationModule();

            wsFAM.PassiveRedirectEnabled = true;
            wsFAM.RequireHttps = true;
            wsFAM.PersistentCookiesOnPassiveRedirects = false;
            wsFAM.Issuer = "https://sts.windows.net/27010d87-5b00-4131-b6fd-fde8346ce198/";
            wsFAM.Realm = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";

            wsFAM.RedirectToIdentityProvider(returnurl, returnurl, false);
        }
        catch { throw; }

    }
```

I get a 404 error but the issuer is definitely correct. Is there any additional parameters to pass for AzureAD.

*Note: I have managed to login with AzureAD in a separate MVC project using an OWIN startup but I ideally need to replicate using my existing setup if possible.*

This is the url which gives a 404: This is the url which I get back: https://sts.windows.net/27010d87-5b00-4131-b6fd-fde8346ce198/?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2flogin.microsoftonline.com%2f27010d87-5b00-4131-b6fd-fde8346ce198%2f&wctx=rm%3d0%26id%3d&wct=2019-11-05T11%3a30%3a51Z&whr=https%3a%2f%2flogin.microsoftonline.com%2f27010d87-5b00-4131-b6fd-fde8346ce198%2f

Comment: If your app is redirecting to https://sts.windows.net/, it is configured wrong. That is the issuer URI, the identifier for the AAD tenant. It isn't an actual URL. login.microsoftonline.com is the correct one where you should be redirecting.

Comment: In azure under Setup SSO. The login url is https://login.microsoftonline.com/27010d87-5b00-4131-b6fd-fde8346ce198/saml2. The Azure AD: https://sts.windows.net/27010d87-5b00-4131-b6fd-fde8346ce198/

Comment: Yeah, that login URL sounds like it might be correct. It's been a very long time since I setup WS-Fed, so I can't really help a lot with that :\

Comment: Ok, not sure why I am being redirected to the STS address. This is the url which I get back: https://sts.windows.net/27010d87-5b00-4131-b6fd-fde8346ce198/?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2flogin.microsoftonline.com%2f27010d87-5b00-4131-b6fd-fde8346ce198%2f&wctx=rm%3d0%26id%3d&wct=2019-11-05T11%3a30%3a51Z&whr=https%3a%2f%2flogin.microsoftonline.com%2f27010d87-5b00-4131-b6fd-fde8346ce198%2f

Comment: Well, if it uses the Issuer as the domain here, then that one is definitely wrong.

Comment: What about the client ID. Should that be passed through somewhere and through hich paramater of WS Federation